# How to remove .php extensions from only one URL?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to remove .php extensions from all files. For example if the user puts example.com/test.php I want to to go to example.com/test and show the page content of test.php

But I want the htaccess file to to this function only on ONE url. Not on all the add-on domains I have

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(test)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(test)/?$ $1.php [L]
```